# Fail to use GLPK solver when python executable triggered with VBA Macros

Tags: python, excel, vba, pyomo, glpk

I am trying to develop an Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP) optimization tool with Excel and Python. Pyomo with GLPK solver are being used for MILP optimization. Python program reads inputs from the excel file and write output to an excel file. I used Pyinstaller to create exe file. The program works when exe file is opened as expected.

The Problem -
I want to trigger the exe file using VBA Macros from the excel file. When the exe file is triggered from the VBA Macro using the Shell() command, the program gives following error - "ValueError: Failed to set executable for solver glpk. File with name=glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe either does not exist or it is not executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with validate=False."

The program works well when exe is directly used and the same program gives the above error when exe file is triggered through VBA Macro. Please help solving this problem.

Edit:

Part of VBA code that calls the exe

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        .Run """" + NewFilePath + """", 1, True
    End With
```

NewFilePath is the location of the exe file.

Please note, GLPK solver works when the exe is executed directly. When called from VBA macro, other sections of python program also works except for the GLPK. The only thing that does not work is GLPK when the exe is called from Macro.

Error Message -

```
WARNING: Failed to create solver with name '_glpk_shell': Failed to set
    executable for solver glpk. File with name=glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe either
    does not exist or it is not executable. To skip this validation, call
    set_executable with validate=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 152, in __call__
  File "pyomo\solvers\plugins\solvers\GLPK.py", line 119, in __init__
  File "pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 55, in __init__
  File "pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py", line 100, in set_executable
ValueError: Failed to set executable for solver glpk. File with name=glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe either does not exist or it is not executable. To skip this validation, call set_executable with validate=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "optimization.py", line 459, in <module>
  File "pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 105, in solve
  File "pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 122, in _solver_error
RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "_glpk_shell"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
        executable: glpk-4.65\w64\glpsol.exe
        type: _glpk_shell
        _args: ()
        options: {}
[15784] Failed to execute script 'optimization' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Some issue with your exe relying on some specific location being the "current directory"?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ Time Williams, Thank you for responding. I doubt the location or the current directory is the problem. The exe including GLPK works when executed directly. Other sections of the Python program (except GLPK) works when executed from VBA. Its just that GLPK do not work when exe file is executed from VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. VBA triggers exe file from the cmd default folder. Python/Pyomo looks for the solver in the same folder. From VBA, by going to the folder in which exe and GLPK solver are from cmd and triggering the exe make the program work. Following is the change

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Cmd1 = "cd " & DistFolder
        Cmd2 = """" + NewFilePath + """"
        Connector = " & "
        Commands = "cmd.exe /K " & Cmd1 & Connector & Cmd2
        .Run Commands, 1, True
    End With
```

@Tim Williams might be right with his comment.